# Articles and comments in one query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

Let's say, i have two tables:

**articles** (articleId,articleDetail)

**comments** (commentId,commentDetail,commentArticle)

I link the **articles** and the **comments** tables with **commentArticle = articleId**

Lets say, I get the articles with this query;

```
SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY articleId DESC
```

The result is;

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [articleId] => 3
            [articleDetail] => The details of article 3
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [articleId] => 2
            [articleDetail] => The details of article 2
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [articleId] => 1
            [articleDetail] => The details of article 1
        )
    ...
)
```

You know, as usual ;)

I want to get the articles and comments with only one query. I tried this;

```
SELECT 
    articles.*,
    comments.*
FROM 
    articles
LEFT JOIN
    comments ON comments.commentArticle = articles.articleId
ORDER BY
    articles.articleId
DESC
```

**No! It didn't work**. I want to get the comments and articles with one query, just like this;

```
Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [articleId] => 3
            [articleDetail] => The details of article 3
            [articleComments] => Array(
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                            [commentId] => 1
                                            [commentDetail] => Details of comment 1
                                            [commentArticle] => 3
                                       )
                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                            [commentId] => 2
                                            [commentDetail] => Details of comment 2
                                            [commentArticle] => 3
                                       )
                                [2] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                            [commentId] => 3
                                            [commentDetail] => Details of comment 3
                                            [commentArticle] => 3
                                       )
                          )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [articleId] => 2
            [articleDetail] => The details of article 2
            [articleComments] => Array( )
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [articleId] => 1
            [articleDetail] => The details of article 1
            [articleComments] => Array(
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                            [commentId] => 4
                                            [commentDetail] => Details of comment 4
                                            [commentArticle] => 1
                                       )
                                [1] => stdClass Object
                                       (
                                            [commentId] => 1
                                            [commentDetail] => Details of comment 5
                                            [commentArticle] => 3
                                       )
                          )
        )
    ...
)
```

Is there a way to do that with a single query? And maybe even, reordering the comments?

Thank you.

Comment: The join works ? You have all your results in one query ? Or the request don't work ?

Comment: This is not possible, you can't have a single result from one table combined with multiple results from another table.

Comment: In postgres you can do it by using "Arrays", but I'm not sure you can do it in SQLite or Oracle... so what is your database?

Comment: @Christian it doesn't have to be an array. I just want to get the sql work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can select this, is to allways have the article info with every comment.
There is no way to do what you want. You will allways get a row with the same amount of columns

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres, you can do it by using arrays:

```
SELECT 
       articles.*,
       array(select comments.single_column 
                    -- or (comments.column1 || '|' || commnets.column2) 
                    -- where '|' is any column separator you wanna use
               from comments 
              where comments.commentArticle = articles.articleId
            ) as comments_array
FROM 
       articles
ORDER BY
       articles.articleId DESC
```

Not sure if other databases (like SQLite/Oracle/etc.) support this kind of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is this:

```
select
  a.articleId,
  articleDetail,
  concat('[', group_concat(
    concat('["commentId"=>"', commentId,
      '", commentDetail=>"', commentDetail,
      '", "commentArticle"=>"', commentArticle, '"]')), ']') comment_array 
from articles a
left join comments c on c.commentArticle = a.articleId
group by 1, 2
order by a.articleId desc
```

This will return a *string* version of a PHP array of arrays for the comments as a single value. It's up to your application to convert this to an actual array of actual arrays.